# jQuery select all list items

Tags: jquery, each

I have this data structure and want to change the content of all my list items inside my ul.

```
<ul class="comments-holder">
  <li class="single-comment-holder">
    <div class="comment-body">
      <div class="comment-text">
        Some Text
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="single-comment-holder">
    <div class="comment-body">
      <div class="comment-text">
        Some Text
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I know there is the each() command in jQuery but I'm not sure how to use it in my context. I'm working with a script that shortens texts for me if they are too long and add a show more button to extend the text. The example I have goes like this:

```
<div class="comment">
  This is a long comment text. 
  This is a long comment text. 
  This is a long comment text. 
  This is a long comment text.
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".comment").shorten();
  });
</script>
```

My question now is how exactly does each work? I thought about using it like this: 
`$(".ul.comments-holder .li.single-comment-holder .comment-body .comment-text").each(shorten(););` but it doesnt work at all. All usage of each I found was in the form `...each(function(){})` so is it even possible to use it like I need to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the extra `.` in your selector and try again like:

```
$("ul.comments-holder li.single-comment-holder .comment-body .comment-text").each(function () {
    $(this).shorten();
});
```

Or a shorter version like

```
$(".comment-text").each(function () {
    $(this).shorten();
});
```

Or just like

```
$(".comment-text").shorten();
```

Comment: So just to understand the syntax a bit better, if I use `$(".comment-text").shorten();` it will look over my whole page for elements with the `class="comment-text"` and use the function with it?

Comment: @user2747192 Yes, it will. But just F.Y.I. `$("ul.comments-holder li.single-comment-holder .comment-body .comment-text")` will also do the same, since jQuerry's Sizzle Engine parse selectors from right to left.

Answer (score 0):

shorten is a plugin, so you need to invoke in on a jQuery wrapper object, also your selector was messed up because you used class selector instead of element selector like `.ul` instead of `ul`

```
$("ul.comments-holder li.single-comment-holder .comment-body .comment-text").shorten()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$("li div.comment-text").each(function() {$(this).shorten()})
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something here, but it's not at all clear that your function is a method of jQuery objects.

*I'm working with a script that shortens texts for me if they are too long*

If your script extends $.fn, then the above answer by palaѕн is great.  If it's just a function, pass it in this way:

```
$(function(){
  $("div.comment-text").each(shorten);
});
```